# Is there a reverse ISNULL() function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, isnull

I have the following code and I am trying to do the following. If `user_time` is not a date then I want the data in `user_date` to be passed on into `user_datetime`. Is there a function that works similarly to `isnull` in sql server that can do this?

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT CASE WHEN isdate(user_time) = 0
THEN user_time = user_date
ELSE null
END AS user_datetime
```

Before:

| user_date(datetimeoffset) | user_time(nvarchar) | user_datetime(datetimeoffset) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | time |  |
| date | bad data (not a time - ignore) |  |

Result:

| user_date(datetimeoffset) | user_time(nvarchar) | user_datetime(datetimeoffset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | time | user_date + user_time combined |
| date | bad data (not a time - ignore) | date |

Comment: `ISNULL`, `TRY_CONVERT`. Not sure why you'd call that a "reverse" `ISNULL`.

Comment: user_date is a datetimeoffset, user_time is a nvarchar and user_datetime is a datetimeoffset

Comment: `user_time is a nvarchar` that's a bug then. Why not use `time` to ensure there's no bad data to begin with? What would you do with the bad data?

Comment: Note that essentially all functions you have for conditional checks boil down to some variation of `CASE` under the hood, some are just more succinct than others. Do prefer `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST` to the "old" `IS...` type checking functions, though, as those have rather unhelpful quirks.

Comment: `datetimeoffset` is already a date *and* time - what do you expect from adding a time?

Comment: Do not just add comments for clarity, edit your question to add that clarity please.

Comment: Please add some sample data for user_date and user_time column.

Comment: Where you have `user_date + user_time combined` do you mean to add additional time `user_time` or to replace the time portion of the `user_date`?
Please give some actual data samples including your desired output - your question title dos not appear to match your desired result but that would help clarify your intent here.

Comment: For anyone hitting this for it's title; the "reverse" of `IsNull` is `NullIf`.  i.e. `select IsNull(@someString, 'The string was null') a, NullIf(@someString, '') b`.  If `@someString` were null then `a` would be `'The string was null'`, `b` would be `null`.  If `@someString` were blank, `a` would be blank, `b` would be `null`.  For any other values, a and b would be `@someString`'s value.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `CAST`. We have to CAST user_date to DATETIME because we cannot add minutes to a type DATE.

> ```
> create table test(
>   user_time varchar(8),
>   user_date date,
>   user_date_time datetime);
>   insert into test (user_time, user_date) values
>   ('10:30:00','20220226'),
>   ('13 hours','20220202');
>   select * from test;
>   
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> user_time | user_date  | user_date_time
> :-------- | :--------- | :-------------
> 10:30:00  | 2022-02-26 | null          
> 13 hours  | 2022-02-02 | null
> ```

> ```
> update test
> set user_date_time =
> CASE WHEN isdate(user_time) = 0
> THEN  user_date
> ELSE cast(user_date as datetime) + cast(user_time as datetime)
> END ;
> select * from test;
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> user_time | user_date  | user_date_time         
> :-------- | :--------- | :----------------------
> 10:30:00  | 2022-02-26 | 2022-02-26 10:30:00.000
> 13 hours  | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00.000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f01c2e40c97c630f37ff02b90428a80a)*

Comment: Those online databases are useful eh? :P  Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string contains a valid time it can be tested by trying to convert it with `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

And use that in a `CASE WHEN`

For example:

> ```
> UPDATE your_table
> SET user_datetime =
>   CASE 
>   WHEN TRY_CAST(user_time AS TIME) IS NOT NULL
>   THEN CAST(CAST(user_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
>      + CAST(TRY_CAST(user_time AS TIME) AS DATETIME) 
>   ELSE user_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
>   END
> WHERE user_datetime IS NULL;
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from your_table;
> ```

> | user_date | user_time | user_datetime |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-01 14:28:44.1630000 -04:00 | 16:00 | 2022-03-01 16:00:00.0000000 +00:00 |
> | 2022-03-01 14:28:44.1630000 +01:00 | Blah | 2022-03-01 13:28:44.1630000 +00:00 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=421004b067b02af91a91eae99205ffb1)*